# DNS Resolution Issue - Unable to resolve domain on specific device

Tags: domain-name-system

I've been unable to open [this website](https://client.wvd.microsoft.com/arm/webclient/) that is a Web client for [Azure Virtual Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/users/connect-web), from my laptop running Linux Mint.

When I try to access the website I get the "Server Not Found" message on Firefox and "This site can’t be reached" - DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN message on Chrome.

I cleaned the DNS cache of my router, OS and browser but still didn't work.

I tried running dig to check if it's a DNS issue:

`$ dig client.wvd.microsoft.com -> "status: SERVFAIL"`
but
`$ dig client.wvd.microsoft.com @1.1.1.1 -> status: NOERROR and returned the DNS records`

So I assumed that my local ISP's DNS resolver was facing some issues. But I tried loading the same page via my phone and a different laptop, both of which are connected to the same Wifi network through the same router and they were able to access the website.

This indicated that my local ISP is actually able to resolve the domain, just not on my laptop.

I changed the DNS IP to Cloudfare 1.1.1.1 in my /etc/resolv.conf file, and the website now opened on my laptop.
After an hour the /etc/resolv.conf file automatically reset so this time I changed my router settings to point to 1.1.1.1 DNS server. I confirmed via https://browserleaks.com/ip that my router uses Cloudfare DNS but still I'm not able to access to website. Only when I specifically change the nameserver from 127.0.0.53:53 to 1.1.1.1 in /etc/resolv.conf does it work.

I'm confused about what exactly is causing this issue. Can someone please help me understand?

Answer (score 1):

(Meta: changed my mind and made an actual answer instead of comments.)

There's no evidence this problem is with your ISP server; recent Ubuntu-family including Mint use systemd-resolved (see its man page, and the comment in resolv.conf) which runs on your own system, hence the 127.0.0.53 entry (127/8 is loopback; also there is no #53 in resolv.conf, only in dig *output*) so the problem can be and I believe is there. If I do `systemd-resolve client.wvd.microsoft.com` on Ubuntu (18.04) it fails claiming 'CNAME loop ... or ... disabled' which appears to be a bug or misfeature; dig on my ISP or *some* public servers gives 9 CNAMEs before succeeding, which is more than usual, but not a loop.

If you want to go back to the old, somewhat less efficient but working, name resolution, there are a few dozen Qs about disabling systemd-resolved in Ubuntu or similar in askubuntu.com and unix.stackexchange.com and I expect at least most of them should work on Mint as well. Alternatively if you manually put this one host-address mapping in your /etc/hosts real programs (but not tools like dig) should use that and not be bothered by the DNS complication.